# Customizing in-text citations to appear in the correct language

Tags: biblatex, greek

I'm using Overleaf to create my Master's dissertation. It's been a wild few days, learning about latex, since it's ruthless to beginners.

One problem I have yet to solve after countless hours looking, is how to correctly implement dual language references.

I need to have greek and english bibliography, and correctly cite my items in-text without any unexpected gibberish.

So far I've used `biblatex`, utilizing both the `keywords` tag and `hyphenation`/`language` which works pretty well with printing the separated bibliography.

However, the in-text citations, that also appear next to the end reference list, are completely messed up for the english text *(my dissertation is almost 100% greek language, I have to use \textlatin before any latin segment).*

This is what's relevant in my main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,bibencoding=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\autocite{RYA2001}

\printbibliography[keyword={en},title={Ξενόγλωσση Βιβλιογραφία}]

\end{document}
```

This is what's relevant in my biblio.bib file:

```
@Book{RYA2001,
  author = {Ryan, Marie-Laure},
  publisher = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
  title = {Narrative as virtual reality : immersion and interactivity in literature and electronic media},
  year = {2001},
  keywords = {en},
  language = {english},
  hyphenation = {english}
}
```

This is the printout for in-text:

`[Ρψα01]`

The printout for the end of document bibliography is good, but its reference to the in-text is the same.

[image: End Reference List]

which is gibberish. I'd like it to appear as `(Ryan, 2001)`, but I can't even use a comma in the bibliography declaration.

How do I correctly setup multi-language citations?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for us to test. This is almost always a necessity for us to be able to answer questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `biblatex` with `style=alphabetic`, so you are getting citations in the form of [ABC00]. You need to use `style=authoryear` to get author year citations.

The citations labels are in Greek, because you need to add `language=auto` to your `biblatex` options. By default, it's `language=autobib`, so the language is only changed in the bibliography.

You can put a comma between the name and the year by redefining the `nameyeardelim` using `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{RYA2001,
  author = {Ryan, Marie-Laure},
  publisher = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
  title = {Narrative as virtual reality : immersion and interactivity in literature and electronic media},
  year = {2001},
  keywords = {en},
  language = {english},
  hyphenation = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,bibencoding=auto,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\autocite{RYA2001}

\printbibliography[keyword={en},title={Ξενόγλωσση Βιβλιογραφία}]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It doesn't work as expected. Switching to `authoryear` breaks the bibliography, specficially telling me I have an empty bibliography file. It also tells me that I'm trying to cite something that doesn't exist (I'm guessing again because of the broken bib file). Finally, it tells me `"Package biblatex Warning: Delimiter 'nameyeardelim' in context '' already defined, overwriting on input line 17.` I didn't change anything in the bib file so as to break it myself.

Comment: @mechanicarts. Do you mean you get that from my exact MWE? Make sure you remove temporary files and recompile (*.aux; *.bbl, *.bcf, etc.). Just changing to `authoryear` shoudn't break the bibliography, so something else is wrong. The warning may be because the version of `biblatex` on overleaf is a bit old I think. Someone else may know if it's significant (I don't get the warning on my system).

Comment: well I added your mwe on a new file, and it worked like a charm. I'm not sure where the problem lies on my actual work. I definitely have trouble pinpointing the error, since I don't have any other code that could mess with the biblio. I even had a friend who regularly authors in LaTeX check my code and there's nothing strange about it.

Comment: I found the error (definitely platform-specific!) From Overleaf, I needed to clear out the cache of "Logs and Other Files", it now works great. I'm still getting the "Delimiter defined" warning, but it doesn't break anything obvious.

Comment: @mechanicarts, You could try `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` instead of `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`

Comment: Error clear! Thanks for all your help!